# Lucene query result as condition for another Lucene statement

Tags: java, database, lucene, polarion

I'm new to Lucene so please be easy on me :D

I am currently trying to write Lucene Statments for data queries in a software called Polarion.
I'm wondering, if there is a possibility to use a Lucene Result as a condition for the next Lucene statement.

My Example:

```
{workitems: type:test AND linkedWorkItems: (**Result of the first Statment**)}
```

The first statement: `{workitems: type:bia AND level:lvl_3}`

If I'm entering the results ID manually  e.g.:

```
{workitems: type:test AND linkedWorkItems: (ABC-1234)}
```

its working as wished!

My goal is to have it all in one statement.
I appreciate any help!

thank you, Jan!

Comment: Just wondering why do you want to do this in 2 steps? You can have both the steps combined as an AND query and that should do the same. In your case, the query would be {workitems: type:test AND (workitems: type:bia AND level:lvl_3) }. You need not go to Lucene twice if can be done in a single call.

Comment: Hi dracula, thank you for your Comment!

The problem is that I'm getting an error when using the "workitems" keyword in the query..
{workitems: type: test AND (workitems: type: bia AND level:lvl_3)}

I am unable to use the result of the "inner" workitems result :/
Error: "com.polarion.subterra.index.QueryIndexException"

When leaving the second "workitems" out there is no Error but there are also no results.

Comment: Hey Jan, is type here a multi-value field? Can 'type' have values - test as well as bia?

Comment: Yes this is possible! For this purpose I'm searching for Results of the type "test". Those results are linked to records from the type "bia". And I want to combine this query into one big. so the results from the bia query can directly be used for the "test" query.

Comment: Okay, so this query should work for you - {type: test AND {type:bia AND level:lvl_3}}. To generate this query, don't run your first statement query against lucene yet. Combine it with second statement query using a BooleanBuilder.

Answer (score -1):

Something like -

```
BooleanBuilder booleanBuilder = new BooleanBuilder();
booleanBuilder.add(first_statement_query, AND);
booleanBuilder.add(second_statement_query, AND);
```

**This will be equivalent to: +(+type:bia +level:lvl_3) +(type:test)**